# 10.04 LTS Update Manager suddenly starts failing

Tags: 10.04, updates, update-manager

All of a sudden my update manager is failing on my 10.04 Ubuntu. It just sits forever with little process indicator spinning

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the answer, but to get past it I would drop to the terminal and run the update from there:

sudo apt-get update  and then; 
sudo apt-get upgrade

After the upgrade and a reboot, I'm guessing that whatever is holding back the update manager will be repaired.

Comment: That's good. Had tried it logged in as a regular user, and failed. Then logged in as administrator and it worked. But now back as regular user, update manager hangs, manual update in terminal fails too, just as regular user, which is how I usually log in. It asks for my regular user password, doesn't echo back anything and then say user name not in sudoer's file.